# How to restore collection in mongodb compass?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-compass

I have changed the collection in MongoDB compass(values of some fields) and I need to restore it to how it was before changing. Unfortunately, I haven`t backup file.

Comment: I'm afraid you answered your own question. No backup = no restore.

Comment: @NicoVanBelle maybe compass creates some copy once per month or something like that?)

Comment: Did you do changes in production?

Comment: @Yash no, it's on test DB